# Firefox slider issue

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have been making a little holiday website and I have been modifying an existing word press theme. However, the website looks fine in Chrome but when I went to check it in Firefox, ouch! I have no idea what happened.

http://rita.adsa.co.uk/

Could someone please point me in the right direction? It's baffling my mind!

Best wishes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `clear: both` to a slider element :)

Answer (score 2):

Define `clear both` of your `#header .smooth_slider`

**As like this**

```
#header .smooth_slider{
clear:both;
}
```

**Result is**

[image]